# How Do Several Trees Merge Into One Hometree?

Tags: avatar

According to Pandorapedia...

> "The name Hometree is misleading, as the structure is actually comprised of a grove of intertwined trees of the same species that have grown together, providing for mutual strength and structural reinforcement."

Just to recap, a single Hometree averages 150 meters tall--a modest enlargement in comparison to the 115.5 meters of Earth's coast redwoods--but there is no info on width, which would help it immensely deal with the issue of height if the Hometree was Terran.

Does anyone have a clear idea on how several small trees merge into one larger tree?

Answer (score 12):

The same way they do in real life: [inosculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inosculation)

> Inosculation is a natural phenomenon in which trunks, branches or roots of two trees grow together. It is biologically similar to grafting and such trees are referred to in forestry terms as Gemels from the Latin word meaning 'A pair'.

The wikipedia page goes on to note that they don't even have to be the exact same species. *Avatar* takes this a bit further by having several rather than just two trees, but it's not really that different.
Life is always stranger than you think.

Comment: I can't find a video to see how that looks.

Comment: You would need a decades long time lapse to see it in action, but the Wikipedia link has a few images. The merged Ash is impressive.